# How to configure the Unicast listener address with dynamic address and port values in Coherence

Tags: oracle-coherence, coherence-toolkit

We are using Coherence concept in our ADF fusion application and using Unicast lister for creating a cluster. 
As of now while running coherence in local we are using the local system address and port values in tangosol-coherence-override.xml file.

How can we update the address and port values as per the environment in tangosol-coherence-override.xml file.

Please suggest us on this.

Regards,
Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml` file in development and `tangosol-coherence-override-prod.xml` in production. According to [Coherence documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/gs_config.htm#COHDG5003):

> - `tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml` – This file overrides operational settings in the `tangosol-coherence.xml` file when Coherence is started in developer mode. By default, Coherence is started in developer mode and the settings in this file are used. The settings in this file are suitable for development environments. The schema file for this override file and the schema for the operational deployment descriptor are the same.
> - `tangosol-coherence-override-prod.xml` – This file overrides operational settings in the `tangosol-coherence.xml` file when Coherence is started in production mode. The settings in this file are suitable for production environments. The schema file for this override file and the schema for the operational deployment descriptor are the same.

If you need more flexibility (e.g. you have separate environments for development, integration testing, staging, etc.), you can use `tangosol.coherence.override` system property to specify configuration file that should be used. Chapters [3.7](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/gs_config.htm#COHDG5027) and [3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/gs_config.htm#COHDG5032) in Coherence documentation explain those configuration possibilities in detail.

Comment: You mean to say we need to use these two xmls in the application with the port and addresses different for Development and Production. ? While running the application coherence will automatically identify the production and dev version xmls ? In that case if we have to test the application in 5 environments then how can we configure the xml ? Please let me know.

Comment: hi Krzysztof, Thank you for the references. As specified, I created tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml and tangosol-coherence-override-prod.xml and created the respective content to be loaded to the specific environment. But I stopped at one point like when running the app, how it will identify that I need to load dev or prod xml. Can please explain a bit more.

Comment: hi Krzysztof, I have read the documentation and came to know we can have multiple override files defined and can access basing on the mode. But my doubt is I have 5 environments like dev, opdev, deva, sita and prod. I created 5 tangasol-coherence-over-(mode).xmls(mode values are - dev, opdev,deva and sita). But how the application know that I am running in dev environment. So I need to load the dev specific xml file. I think there will be a way for this also which I am unable to fine. May be I am understanding the documentation wrongly. Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

Comment: You can switch between `dev` and `prod` modes using `tangosol.coherence.mode` system property. But this property can by only set to one of those two predefined values and is somehow connected with licencing issues, so it will not be suitable for specifying another environments (eg. opdev, deva, etc.). Use `tangosol.coherence.override` property instead. You can set it as a VM argument when starting application (e.g. `-Dtangosol.coherence.override=tangasol-coherence-over-opdev.xml`).

Comment: hi Krzysztof, I added the tangosol.coherence.mode as dev in tangasol-coherence-override.xml and created a new tangasol-coherence-override-dev.xml with the required configurations. When I run the application, it is picking up the tangasol-coherence-override-dev.xml and creating the required cache as expected. It seems like the regular approach. I still didn't understand what is actual use of having these two modes. Is there any way that we can add both of these dev and prod xmls and load them automatically basing on the environment ? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, to make our requirement more clear, it is like we need to configure the unicast listener address and port values of the environment in our application env.properties. We will be having env.properties defined for each environment. The application picks up the specific env.properties and need to update the address and port values. We are trying to find a solution like this. But we don't know whether it is possible in coherence or not.

Comment: I don't know about `env.properties` file and how it is processed. If those properties are read on startup and exposed as system properties (available through `System.getProperty(propertyName)` ), then all you need is to add an entry like `tangosol.coherence.override=tangasol-coherence-over-opdev.‌​xml` in this file. If they are not exposed as system properties, then you might do it by yourself (read this configuration and call `System.setProperty("tangosol.coherence.override", value)` ) prior to starting Coherence node. Unfortunately, I don't know ADF, so I cannot help you further with this.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, I tried with the System.getProperty approach and it is working fine as we expected. Thank you for your suggestion. :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: hi Krzysztof, I am trying to do the same in our one of the environment and it is identifying the override xml but I am getting an exception like below.       Exception occured in creating coherence cluster::::java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start Service "Cluster" (ServiceState=SERVICE_STOPPED, STATE_JOINING). Any idea on this error ?

Comment: I have no idea. But you could try googling for `Failed to start Service "Cluster" ` - it shows a couple of results that might give you a clue.